# node.js proxy for all websites

Tags: node.js, proxy, http-proxy

I am trying to make a node.js proxy for basically using on all websites, I have got as following so far, but it seems that the URL may be a circular object... so for example, when i go to localhost:3000/google.com , it goes to google.com/google.com, and same if i go to example.com... I am wondering how i could make it only go to the URL specified?

```
const httpProxy = require('http-proxy');
const proxy = httpProxy.createProxyServer();

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;

require('http').createServer((req, res) => {
  const targetUrl = req.url.slice(1).replace(/^https?:\/\//, ''); // remove leading slash and protocol prefix
  console.log(targetUrl)
  proxy.web(req, res, {
    target: `http://${targetUrl}`, // add the protocol back in
  });
}).listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Proxy server running on port ${PORT}`);
});
```

I have tried a variety of solutions, even replacing the http-proxy module altogether , but i think fixing this is the best option...?

Comment: What is the output of console.log(targetUrl) for localhost:3000/google.com?

Comment: @IamDOM The output is this: google.com
favicon.ico. favicon.ico only happens sometimes i think? but when it does, it comes back with an error as well. Uncaught Error Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND favicon.ico

Comment: nevermind, i just realized i was using a different version of the code. Anywway,  for the kind of working one, (which is the one i currently have here),  it is simply google.com by the looks of things